# Visual Studio locates systemjs typescript definitions, but cannot locate them on compile

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015, typescript1.8

I have a TypeScript project in Visual Studio, with modules installed via systemjs. I have the following code:

**app.ts**

```
import { Aurelia } from 'aurelia-framework';
```

For example, hovering Aurelia and pressing F12 (Go to Definition) opens up the correct `aurelia-framework.d.ts` file installed by systemjs. However, when I click Build, I get the following output:

```
error TS2307: Build: Cannot find module 'aurelia-router'.
```

Here is my tsconfig for reference.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "version": "1.8.0",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "src/",
    "outDir": "dist/",
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Aurelia just refuses to play nicely with Typescript in VS2015, doesn't it?  I can get the ES2015 skeletons to run but the TS compiler refuses to allow my projects to even start, regardless of the fact that they compile perfectly via gulp.

Comment: Of course, it may be different with .NET Core but let's be realistic - a lot of webhosts don't support Core, there are a whole lot of MVC1-5 projects out there that will need a modern JS framework attached...

It's a huge pain.

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to be to add a file - I call mine typings.d.ts - in the root of your aurelia app - /src or whatever you've called it - with a single /// reference to the index.d.ts file in your typings folder.

Then everything plays nice.